# how to get android browser files and list it

Tags: android, file, delphi, browser, internal

I am programming an app using Delphi for Android. I am having a problem loading files from this dir:

```
/data/data/com.htc.sense.browser/databases
```

Whenever I press the button, the listbox is empty !!

```
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
  Files: TStringDynArray;
  s: string;
begin
  FileList.Clear;
  Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(Path);
  for s in Files do
    FileList.Add(s);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListFileDir('/data/data/com.htc.sense.browser/databases/', ListBox1.Items);            
end;
```

Comment: The name in the code doesn't match the name in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/data/data/<package name>` folder, and its subfolders, are private to the app that owns `<package name>` and cannot be accessed by other apps unless it explicitly sets permissions on the folder and/or its files to allow access (which Google does not recommend doing).

IOW, if HTC does not want you accessing its `/databases` folder, you cannot list its files (unless you root your device, for instance).

Comment: well, my devise is rooted, is there a way to do it? in Delphi?.

Comment: thank you, but im not looking about installing fonts!, and sorry Mr.Remy there is not much articles about Delphi language and android, many thanks agine

Comment: Sorry, I posted that comment in the wrong discussion.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you already have access to everything, so there should be no trouble accessing `/data/data/<package name>` folders.